# Share content on Facebook without opening a popup

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I have one button and I want to share the content on Facebook without opening Facebook dialogue box.

Present code works like:

1. Click on a button;
2. It opens Facebook share dialogue;
3. And again click on share from dialogue;

I want something like this: click on a button and it would be shared on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed#publish

You would need to authorize the user with `publish_actions` to do that. You need to go through the [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) process with that permission and the message parameter must be 100% user generated according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

A lot of things to consider, i´d just stick to the popup.

Comment: will this avoid to use popup ?
Is there anyway to invoke facebook share dialogue box ?

Comment: feed publishing will avoid the popup, yes. but as i commented, you need to authorize the user and whatnot. you can´t just invoke the share dialog, that would definitely not allowed - if it would be possible. what i answered is the only possibility to do share without the dialog.